# Book to learn basics of number theory?

Tags: book-recommendation

I would like to hear some easy books to learn basics of number theory from.

I have almost no knowledge about topic to start with, so book should start with very basics. I'm currently on high school, but the book would be used just for personal interest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try [*A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory*](http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/frint.html) by Joseph H. Silverman.

The first six chapters are freely available.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also a high school student, and I am reading [*Number Theory* by George Andrews](https://archive.org/stream/NumberTheory_862/Andrews-NumberTheory#page/n0/mode/2up) because it was advertised as accessible, but did not find it to be very much so. It is pretty difficult for me, but very interesting and rewarding. I would recommend it if you are willing to do a lot of work and thinking!